# Random Numbers with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have the following code to generate two random numbers

```
var attackRoll = Math.floor((Math.random()*6)+1);
var defenceRoll = Math.floor((Math.random()*6)+1);
```

When I run this code, it will generate two random numbers as expected. The only thing I notice, I wish to just ask to make sure I am not going crazy is... The first variable will always have the higher "Roll" or "Equal I have run this code an output the values so many, many times and not once has the second value been higher than that of the first.

Is this just me being silly? Or have I assigned the random numbers incorrectly?

Comment: For sanity's sake, have you tried swapping the lines so `defenceRoll` runs first?

Comment: 2nd was higher for me on the 2nd try.  There's no reason these shouldn't be random.

Comment: Yeah, I did this before posting the question, alternating it means the variable that never had the higher number now does have the higher number, and the old "winning" variable will only ever at best draw with the new higher variable

Comment: [Here is a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pointy/ncxrg/) showing, I think, that you may be misinterpreting the situation.

Comment: I see a pretty nice split:  http://jsfiddle.net/KFtTr/

Comment: It would seem it may be just a terrible coincidence for me then?!

Comment: No, @RoryStandley, that is simply impossible.  You can't suffer from a "coincidence" that involves a statistically unlikely thing happening to you over and over again. Instead, consider the possibility that your analysis of the cause of your problem may be incorrect (in fact, it is almost guaranteed to be incorrect).

Comment: Perhaps you could post the code you used that lead you to decide that the results of the random number generation are anomalous.  There's no debugging code in what you posted; have you added any?

Comment: @Pointy When I say a coincidence, I say it would seem that it works correctly just giving the appearance that it is not correct as one value seems to always be hgiher than the other.

Comment: Has Math.random been redefined somehow?!  What's your JS engine?  Are you using a browser?  Which one?  JS is seeded psuedo random, it is supposed to be seeded with a random integer every time your engine is initialised (e.g. current timestamp).  If your implementation of JS doesn't do this, then that would cause your Math.random() calls to be predictable - can you output the result of Math.random() itself.  Are these values repeated every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean that `attackRoll` is always greater than or equal than `defenceRoll`? **Absolutely not**. In fact the probability of one being higher than the other is <del>50%</del> equal.

Can you support your claims with a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)? Have you tried in different browser?

Comment: It's not 50% when you consider the two being equal.  I agree otherwise.

Comment: @JamesMontagne: theoretically speaking, the probability of two continuous random variables being equal approaches 0 (1 value vs. infinite number). But since `float` is really discrete... Correcting my answer, thanks :-).

Comment: Wait, are you saying if you pick two numbers at random the probability of them being equal approaches 0?  These numbers are bounded (a very low bound at that).  Did I misunderstand?

Comment: @JamesMontagne: if you pick any **real** number (let's say from <0;1> - i said *continuous random variables*), what is the probability of picking, e.g. *0.3*? The sample space is infinite. Now generalize to picking two random real numbers - what is the probability of them being equal?

Comment: Okay, in that case I agree, but that doesn't apply to picking integers from 1-6.  That was my confusion.

Comment: @JamesMontagne: Oh gosh, I totally forgot about `Math.floor` in the question, sorry! In discrete space of course the probability is way higher.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a **single user error** - take a look at this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e584p/), and you should find that the second number will be diverse:
the same, 
higher, 
or lower 
than the first number.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want. To get one dice roll and another that is higher or equal use this:

```
var sides = 6;
var firstRoll = Math.floor((Math.random()*sides)+1);
var secondRoll = Math.floor((Math.random()*(sides+1-firstRoll)+firstRoll); // a lucky one :)
```

If you want to rolls and have the higher in the first variable, use

```
var sides = 6;
var firstRoll = Math.floor((Math.random()*sides)+1);
var secondRoll = Math.floor((Math.random()*sides)+1);
if (firstRoll >= secondRoll) {
    higherRoll = firstRoll; // attackRoll
    lesserRoll = secondRoll; // defenceRoll
} else {
    higherRoll = secondRoll; // attackRoll
    lesserRoll = firstRoll; // defenceRoll
}
```

Comment: No, that's not what the issue is, I don't think. The OP thinks his random numbers are not random.

Comment: Ah, OK. I didn't believed he really would mean to ask that.